# Loop through QLabels in HBoxLayout

Tags: qt

I have an HBoxLayout with different QLabels inside. I want to loop through all those QLabels and set the text to an empty string. I tried the following, but nothing happens:

```
void MainWindow::addLabelItem() {
    const QList<QLabel*> labels = ui->hBoxLabels->findChildren<QLabel*>();
    for (QLabel *label : labels) {
        if (label->text() == "Head") {
            label->setText("");
        }
    }

    ui->hBoxLabels->addWidget(new QLabel("Head"));
}
```

Where do I go wrong? Thanks :)

Comment: change `if (label->text() == "Head") {
            label->setText("");
        }` to `label.clear()`, provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc Unfortunately, the result is the same

Comment: provide  a [mre]

Comment: The MRE is an important part of your question so it should not be in an external resource as a link but in your own question, so edit your question and add all the information there. You have already asked 29 questions so you should know that rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution:

```
void MainWindow::addLabelItem() {
    for (int i = 0; i < ui->hBoxLabels->count(); ++i) {
        QLayout *layout = ui->hBoxLabels->layout();
        QLabel *label = qobject_cast<QLabel*>(layout->itemAt(i)->widget());
        if (label->text() == "Head") {
            label->setText("");
        }
    }

    ui->hBoxLabels->addWidget(new QLabel("Head"));
}
```